# python's timeit is not initialising list in setup code

Tags: python, list, set, timeit

I'm timing element removal from a python `set` vs. a `list`. My timeit code for the list is raising a `ValueError: ... x not in list`, but only when I run more than one iteration with `timeit` !??

It appears that for the list, the variable created in the setup code is re-used in the subsequent iteration (as if the setup code is not run the second time??).

Here's my code:

```
In [1]: import timeit

In [2]: timeit.timeit(stmt='a.discard(10**5)', setup='a = set(range(10**6))', number=100000)
Out[2]: 0.02187999989837408

In [3]: timeit.timeit(stmt='a.remove(10**5)', setup='a = list(range(10**6))', number=1)
Out[3]: 0.023419374600052834

In [4]: timeit.timeit(stmt='a.remove(10**5)', setup='a = list(range(10**6))', number=2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

What's going on??

Comment: @Laurent H. Happy to use US/UK spelling with -ize, but I'm Australian and -ise is [acceptable spelling here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macquarie_Dictionary#preferred_spellings)

Comment: I really apologize to Australian pepole. You have learnt me something, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They key point is that `setup` is only performed *once* even when `number` is >1 (hence the `ValueError` when you try call to `list.remove` with a unique value that has already been removed from the list).  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) (emphasis mine):

> Time number executions of the main statement. **This executes the setup
>   statement once**, and then returns the time it takes to execute the main
>   statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float. The
>   argument is the number of times through the loop, defaulting to one
>   million. The main statement, the setup statement and the timer
>   function to be used are passed to the constructor.

So, if you want to perform multiple timings of a code snippet like this (say to get more accurate timings) then you have to use `number=1`, but you could use the `repeat` argument with `timeit.repeat()` instead:

```
>>> timeit.repeat(stmt='a.remove(10**5)', setup='a = list(range(10**6))', number=1, repeat=2)
[0.002321417909115553, 0.0023121219128370285]
```

Comment: fwiw, removing from `set`s is always faster, and especially for long `list`s, where it's much faster (for 10k elements, 10x to remove first element, 200x for last element).

Comment: @drevicko Right, that makes sense in terms of time complexity since `set.remove` is normally an O(1) operation (just calculating a hash) while `list.remove` is an O(n) operation (potentially examining every item in the whole list)

Comment: also, removing the first item has a hit since the remaining items need to be shifted in memory afaik (though that's pretty efficient actually)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [4]: timeit.timeit(stmt='a.remove(10**5)', setup='a = list(range(10**6))', number=2)
```

`a.remove(10**5)` is executed twice but 10**5 can only be removed once. The `setup` is only called ONCE so you always work on the same list or set.

This is equivalent to

```
a = list(range(10**6))
a.remove(10**5)  # works
a.remove(10**5)  # fails with ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

This doesn't fail for the set since set discard and list remove behave differently.
If you use set remove method you will also end up getting an error (KeyError)

```
a = set(range(10**6))
a.discard(10**5)  # works
a.discard(10**5)  # works
```

but

```
a = set(range(10**6))
a.remove(10**5)  # works
a.remove(10**5)  # KeyError 10**5
```

Answer (score 0):

The `discard()` operation on sets does nothing if the element being discarded is not in the set. The `remove()` operation on lists, however, raises a `ValueError` when the element does not exist. When you initialize your list with `range(10**6)`, the value `10**5` only appears once; in the set this isn't a problem, but in the list it can only be removed once and will give an error on future attempts to remove the same value.